# Hot to use results from procedure calls as conditions

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have a procedure that checks for a condition (if a session is fully booked). I want to make a trigger that checks if the session is fully booked before inserting a new booking.

What I imagine it would be like is something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_if_session_is_full_trigger()
   RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
     IF (EXECUTE session_is_full(NEW.session_id)) THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'SESSION IS FULLY BOOKED';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I get this

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "session_is_full"
LINE 5:      IF (EXECUTE session_is_full(NEW.session_id) = TRUE) THE...
```

So obviously I'm not doing something right.

session_is_full(int) returns boolean.

Am I on the right track, and how to fix this?

Comment: `IF (session_is_full(NEW.session_id))` should work

Comment: thanks, it's weird, because I was making another trigger before and it wouldnt work without the execute statement. Can you post on a seperate post so I can close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF (session_is_full(NEW.session_id)) should work – @a_horse_with_no_name